# Php bad exif_read_data?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, file-upload, exif

I am using some software built with php. Its for a car dealership website.
rpnmotorsinc.net

The problem is being able to upload images. If I upload most jpg or jpeg files, they usually upload with no problem. Since my client does not want to resize/resave images, he is wanting to take photos directly from his Canon camera to the computer to upload to website, again without having to resize or resave. These images range from 3 to 4 MB in size.

Here is the error message I receive while trying to upload these images:

**Warning: exif_read_data(IMG_7B78AC-0BE18D-FEEBCB-6DED45-5C0BF2-780393.jpg): IFD data bad offset: 0xFFFFFD10 length 0x0ED42**

The images seem to upload, but they throw errors and it seems to take a while to upload. I know they are large in file size, but what I am expecting is a little faster upload and to not show any errors.

Here is my php/server info https://rpnmotorsinc.net/phpinfo.php

How can I fix this?

Comment: _"I am using some software built with php"_ - what software is this?

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue with a phpBB bulletin board.

I added a routine to rotate and resize pictures at upload. Works like a charm except with original canon photos. 
I have to change the exif-data and save the picture - then it works. 
I know, this isn´t a solution, but maybe it helps finding one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to relate to a known [bug of PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72914). I found a solution using [ExifTool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) before uploading a picture that generated this error:

> exiftool -X photo.jpg > photo.xml
>
> exiftool -tagsfromfile photo.xml -all:all photo.jpg
>       1 image files updated

The first command saves the EXIF metadata to a separate XML file, and the second reconstructs them from there. This is obviously not a good solution for the original question because it requires even more work from your customer than just resizing the picture. If you can install ExifTool on your server, however, you may be able to run it after any new upload.